# Google apps script / javascript 2D array typeerror

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

My intention is to make a small quiz-script using Google apps script. The data for the questions and possible answers reside in a Google spreadsheet. Range in the spreadsheet is called by the script and used as an 2d Array. Most of the times the script runs fine, but sometimes a

> 'typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined'

seems to pop up randomly.

I am probably using the array functionality wrong, but I cant get my head around it.

1 In most examples regarding arrays a for loop is used. Since the data in my array wouldnt change, would using this for loop still be mandatory?

2 Would it be beneficial to store the spreadsheet data into cache?

```
function drawQuestion (){

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var cache = CacheService.getPrivateCache();

  //Add Spreadsheet DB
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var min =1;
  var max = MAX;
  var xnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

  //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var question1 = String(data[xnumber][0]);  //when I change this '0' in a '1' it gives me a typeerror cannot read property 1 - message.
    var answer1 = String(data[xnumber][1]);
    var answer2 = String(data[xnumber][2]);
    var answer3 = String(data[xnumber][3]);
    var answer4 = String(data[xnumber][4]);
    var correct1 = Number(data[xnumber][5]);
   // var background1 = data[xnumber][6];
   // var explanation1 = data[xnumber][7];
 // }  


  //Write the new Question
  var statusLabel = app.getElementById("statusLabel");
   statusLabel.setText(question1);
  //Answer1
  var button1 = app.getElementById("button1");
  button1.setText(answer1);

  //Answer2
  var button2 = app.getElementById("button2");
  button2.setText(answer2);
  //Answer3
  var button3 = app.getElementById("button3");
  button3.setText(answer3);
  //Answer4
  var button4 = app.getElementById("button4");
  button4.setText(answer4);

  //Store correct answer & explanation in cache
  cache.put('correct1', Number(correct1));
  //cache.put('explanation1', explanation1);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says your `data[xnumber]` is not defined during that instance. you are accesing index `0` of undefined object. Before using `data[xnumber][0]` verify `data[xnumber]` and `data[xnumber][0]` are valid.

Also in your code please verify your value of `xnumber`.

By using this expression your `xnumber` can have any value (not guarantee that in between `0` and `max`)

```
var xnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
```

Also there is no constraint on using an Array inside a loop. but it will safeguard against these type of errors by having a proper validating condition for the loop

Comment: You're right. I missed the fact that arrays start with [0]. So MAX was defined at a higher number than the available rows in the spreadsheet; Having no validation implemented allowed this error to be produced.

Any feedback on my second question? cache vs spreadsheet link?